# Equations with Chebyshev polynomials

Tags: numerical-methods, roots, orthogonal-polynomials

For a natural number n, let $r(x)$ be the polynomial $$r(x)=\prod_{k=1}^n(x-2\sin(\frac{\pi k}{2n+1})).$$ Then $-xr(2x)r(-2x)$ is Chebyshev polynomial of the first kind with integer coefficients.
 There are two questions with applications to solving difference equations:

1. Is there a closed formula for the coefficients of $r(x)$?
2. Let $$q(x^2)=r(x)+r(-x)$$ and $$xp(x^2)=r(x)-r(-x),$$ then the roots of $p(x)$ and $q(x)$ are negative and interlace. Is there an explicit formula for the roots?

Comment: Is there a typo in the question ? I don't agree with the assumption : $xr(x)r(-x)$ is a normalized Chebyshev polynomial of the first kind with integer coefficients. For example, in the case $n=1 \quad\to\quad r(x)=x-2\sin(\pi/3)\quad\to\quad xr(x)r(-x)=-x^3+3x\quad$ which isn't a Chebyshev polynomial of the first kind.

Comment: @JJacquelin It's a NORMALIZED Chebyshev polynomial: $-xr(2x)r(-2x)=4x^3-3x$.

Comment: In the wording of your question you wrote : Then $xr(x)r(-x)$ is a normalized Chebyshev polynomial of the first kind with integer coefficients. Now you write :  $-xr(2x)r(-2x)=4x^3-3x$. Why mysteriously $x$ becomes $2x$ ?

Comment: @JJacquelin Sorry, maybe was a bit sloppy, edited the question...